# What search terms should I use when creating alert that is triggered when there are no logs coming from service in Splunk?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I want to trigger an alert when there are no logs coming from our services in Splunk but not sure how to do that.

I can search our logs using this `[| inputlookup app | search app=app_name env=prod service=app_name]` where app is the csv lookup table with app, env, and service properties that provide lookup values for our search.

One other thing to note is I have access to the sourcetype or the source where

```
sourcetype=kube:container:app_name_env
source=*k8s_app_name_env_*
```

But again, not sure what search query I should create the alert based on. I know how to create alerts in splunk but not sure how to trigger it if there are no logs coming from the source above. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Alert actions, have it send a message when there are no results:

[image]